# WIN32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration does not report IP from PPP adapter

Tags: windows-7, wmi, ipconfig

On a Windows 7 device, the following WMI query does not report back an enabled PPP adapter:

```
Select Index,MACAddress,IPAddress,IPSubnet,DefaultIPGateway,DNSServerSearchOrder from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled=true
```

Where **ipconfig** gives you all the information correctly:

> Windows IP Configuration
>
> PPP adapter XYZ VPN:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :
>   123.456.789.123
>   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
>   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
>   0.0.0.0
>
> Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network
>   Connection:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :
>   192.168.178.11
>   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
>   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
>   192.168.178.1
>
> Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection
>   3:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Any ideas how I can script this by using WMI or VBS?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same problem on Win7(x86).

Answer (score 2):

This is a [bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2549091) that was present in Vista and hasn't gotten fixed through Windows 7 or Windows 8.

You must use either .NET or C++ APIs to get this information. I think the easiest thing to do is to use Powershell with .NET:

```
$nics = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
foreach ($nic in $nics) {
    write-host $nic.name
    write-host "MAC Address $($nic.GetPhysicalAddress)"
    $props = $nic.GetIPProperties()
    $addresses = $props.UnicastAddresses
    foreach ($addr in $addresses) {
        write-host "IP Address: $($addr.Address.IPAddressToString)"
        write-host "IPv4 Mask: $($addr.IPv4Mask.IPAddressToString)"
    }
    write-host "Gateway: $($props.GatewayAddresses.Address.IPAddressToString)"
    write-host "DNS Server(s): $($props.DnsAddresses.IPAddressToString)"
    write-host ""
}
```

See [the NetworkInterface class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface(VS.85).aspx) for information on using that .NET class with C#, VB, or C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
On Error Resume Next

strComputer= "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled=TRUE")

For Each objItem In colItems
      strIPAddress = Join(objItem.IPAddress, ",")

      WScript.Echo "IPAddress: " & strIPAddress

Next
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question!